# All forms redirect to login page - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a little problem with forms. All forms after pressing submit button redirect the user to login page. No matter what url I put in the form it gets redirected to Login Page.

Here is my registration code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Account\Account;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Security\EmailVerifier;
use App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;


class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            
        ]);
    }
}
```

And template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body_id 'login' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('register') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<section class="container mt-3 text-white">
    <div class="post">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        
        <form action='{{ path('app_register') }}' class='form' method="POST">
            <p class='field required'>
                <label class='label required' for='name'>{{ 'label.username'|trans }}</label>
                <input class='text-input' type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control"/>
            </p>
            <p class='field required'>
                <label class='label required' for='email'>Email</label>
                <input class='text-input' type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" />                
            </p>
            <p class='field required'>
                <label class='label required' for='password'>{{ 'label.password'|trans }}</label>
                <input class='text-input' type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" />                
            </p>    
            <p class='field'>
                <input class='button' type='submit' value='Register'>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
</div>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

Do you know about any reason for it to happen? It happens with every form in the project. Even if I use form builder. All submit buttons redirect you to login page. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit the code in Controller. You can try:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //TODO: check login (your code here)
    }
    return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
        
    ]);
}
```